# Not able to export the desired results in R

Tags: r, excel, latitude-longitude

I have a square mesh of latitudes and longitudes for a geographical region. However I only know the latitude and longitude values of the 4 corners of this mesh. Using these I need to calculate the lat-long values at all the cross hairs. So, I separately crested a nested loop program in **R** for latitudes and longitudes.

```
   tllong<-67.481961

   sink("output_long.txt")
   for (i in c(1:11447)) {
     for (j in c(1:10335)) {
       tllong<- 67.481961 + (j-1)*0.0030769
       print(tllong)
     }

    }
    sink()
```

The above program was for calculating longitudes.  *tllong* is the value of longitude at top left corner of the mesh. 11447 are the number of latitudes and 10335 are the number of longitudes.

Similarly I created a program for calculating latitudes.

```
    tllat<-36.348639

    sink("output_lat_again.txt")
    for (i in c(1:11447)) {
      for (j in c(1:10335)) {
        print(tllat)
      }
      tllat<- tllat - (i-1)*0.002508
    }
    sink()
```

*tllat* is the value of latitude of the top left corner mesh square.

So as you can see that the loop first calculate all the lat,long values for first row Then goes to second row, then third and so on. However when I get the exported text files for both the programs, I get a single column containing all the values. This is not much of a use for me. I tried to export the output results of R in **xlsx** format using **sink("output_long.xlsx")** but when I get the excel file (after 4-5 hours of constant long run of loop) I fail to open it. The error message shows either the file is corrupted or file is of different format. I have tried this 3-4 times but in vain.

So how do I export the results of these two programs in an excel file such that I do not get all the values in a single column but in an appropriate matrix form (i.e. the values of lat,long in each cell corresponds to the values of lat,long in the corresponding cross hair of the mesh).

Also, it would be nice if someone can tell me how to run these two programs together so that I can get the lat-long values in a single run in the same file.

Comment: sink creates a text file not an excel file. You also don't need any loops. Something like i <- 0:10; j <- 0:10; res <- expand.grid(startx - cumsum(i) * dx, starty - cumsum(j) * dy) should work and you can then export the result using write.csv or even one of the packages that can create excel files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to create 10335*11447=118304745 pairs of lat/lon values. It's a pretty big number. Is that correct? However, I will show the procedure applied to a smaller example. Try this:

```
#setting the values of parameters
tllong<-67.481961
tllat<-36.348639
deltalong<-0.0030769
deltalat<-0.002508
#small example: you can set the following to the real values
nlong<-10
nlat<-10
#create vectors of values without loops 
lat<-seq(tllat,by=deltalat,length.out=nlat)
lon<-seq(tllong,by=deltalong,length.out=nlong)
#now we build every possible pair of lat/lon values
latlong<-expand.grid(lon=lon,lat=lat)
#we export it to a csv file
write.csv(latlong,"somefile.csv",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
```

At the end, the `somefile.csv` will be created. Keep in mind that, with your values, the created file will be very big.

Comment: Thanks and you are absolutely correct. I need lat-long values as coordinates in a cell. Even two adjacent columns of a lat and its corresponding long will also work.  I tried running this program but my system hanged and I had to terminate the process. I don't know why is this happening. Last time when I ran my loop program, it took around 4-5 hours to get completely executed but it never hanged. Is there anything that I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: At what point does it hang? On the `expand.grid()` or `write.csv()` call? At 100 million + these can be expensive memory footprints to make at once though they are vectorized. @nicola can adjust to loop iteratively dump to txt with `sapply()` or `outer()` for all possible combinations between vectors. Or process data in chunks.